# Homebrew requirements breaking rvm requirements on Yosemite

Tags: rvm, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Updated to Yosemite on an iMac(mid 2010) and an Air(late 2010). My developer environment [rvm 1.25.33, ruby 2.1.2, homebrew] has no issues on the iMac, but the Air errors out when I try to run rvm requirements:

```
Checking requirements for osx.  
Installing requirements for osx.  
Updating system.....  
Installing required packages: gcc46, libyaml, readline, libksba....  
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc46 libyaml readline libksba',  
showing last 15 lines of   
/Users/michael/.rvm/log/1413996850/package_install_gcc46_libyaml_readline_libksba.log  
+ case "$1" in  
+ [[ -t 1 ]]  
+ return 1  
+ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.  

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'  
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation  
+ case "$_system_version" in  
+ return 1  
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I can manually install all of those files except gcc46, which errors out every time. Yes, I installed CLT 6.1(several times), but homebrew seems to ignore that and insists on installing gcc46 as a dependency.

Brew update and brew doctor says everything is fine. The log states:

```
Installing gcc46 from homebrew/homebrew-versions  
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.  
gcc46: OS X Mavericks or older is required for stable.  
Use `brew install devel or --HEAD` for newer."
```

It seems illogical to brew install --HEAD gcc46 while gcc49 is already available, but after two days empty research and wrestling with this, I tried and got:

```
No head is defined for gcc46
```

I've reinstalled Homebrew and rvm four times only to run into the same error each time. I might just chalk this up to simple incompatibility if it were not for the fact that my iMac has no issues with the update. My developer environment is identical on both systems. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on two OSX machines just upgraded to Yosemite. Also note that this happens with either Xcode 6.0.1 and 6.1 installed. I've tried with both versions and get this same error in both scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to update rvm:

```
rvm get head
```

I'm about to push next stabled so tomorrow it will be enough to get stable:

```
rvm get stable
```

Comment: I guess I just needed a little patience for the process :) After I updated one tick to rvm 1.25.34, the issue disappeared. I didn't even need to reinstall again. _Thanks, devs!!!_

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issues on a 2013 MBP. What finally seemed to do the trick was completely uninstalling xCode and CLT, then reinstalling both (with that nice long xCode download). After that I was finally able to run `rvm requirements` successfully and continue on with my day.

Another thing of note, I did run `rvm get head` before all of this to ensure I had the most up-to-date rvm build. Not sure if that had an impact in the long run, but I do believe completely re-installing xCode is what finally did the trick.

Best of luck!